# I'm not getting my "var c" value inside my text box with the ID="two" rather undefined is displayed, please help me with this situation

Tags: javascript, html

```
       function prime_number()
{ 
            var num, i, c, flag = true;
            num = parseInt(document.getElementById("one").value);
            for(i = 2; i <= num - 1; i++)
            {
                if(num % i === 0)
                    {
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                
                if (flag === true)
                    var c = "It is a prime number";
                else 
                    var c = "It is not a prime number";
            }
    document.getElementById("two").value = c;
}
```

**THIS IS THE CODING FOR FORM**

```
 <form>
        <input type="number" id="one" name="one" placeholder="Enter a positive number"><br>
        <input type="text" id="two" name="two"><br>
        <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="CHECK" onclick="prime_number()"><br>
    </form>
```

I've tried the **ALERT** method to show the text **"THIS IS A PRIME NUMBER" or "THIS IS NOT A PRIME NUMBER"** and that worked.

Comment: Use `c = xxx` instead of `var c = xxxx` when you assign value to it

Answer (score 1):

Because your assignments of `c` are withing the for loop, when the loop breaks your assigmnents don't get executed. So, take em out of the for loop, secondly don't redefine `c` with `var`.

```js
function prime_number() { 
  var num, i, c, flag = true;
  num = parseInt(document.getElementById("one").value);
  for(i = 2; i <= num - 1; i++) {
    if(num % i === 0)
    {
      flag = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(c);
    if (flag === true)
       c = "It is a prime number";
    else 
       c = "It is not a prime number";
  document.getElementById("two").value = c;
}
```

```html
<form>
        <input type="number" id="one" name="one" placeholder="Enter a positive number"><br>
        <input type="text" id="two" name="two"><br>
        <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="CHECK" onclick="prime_number()"><br>
    </form>
```

P.S: You can make a more efficient check in the for loop as:
`for(i = 2; i <= num/2; i++)`

A number cannot be divisible by more than it's half, so you don't need to test those scenarios, i.e.
`x % (x/2 + epsilon)` is never 0.

Answer (score 0):

Two points needs to pay attention:

1. use `c = xxx` instead of `var c = xxx` when you assign value to it
2. need to assign value to `c` outside `for` loop

```js
function prime_number()
{ 
  var num, i, c, flag = true;
  num = parseInt(document.getElementById("one").value);
  for(i = 2; i <= num - 1; i++)
  {
      if(num % i === 0)
          {
              flag = false;
              break;
          }
  }
  
  if (flag){
     c = "It is a prime number";
   }else{
      c = "It is not a prime number";
   }
  document.getElementById("two").value = c;
}
```

```html
<form>
        <input type="number" id="one" name="one" placeholder="Enter a positive number"><br>
        <input type="text" id="two" name="two"><br>
        <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="CHECK" onclick="prime_number()"><br>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use same c = "It is a prime number" etc. because when you use var c again you declare variable c again, but it already exists.

Comment: This type of information is helpful, but since it's not answering the question, it would be better suited as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

**I did the same, as you guys guided me and it all went well. I just needed to correct the ';' and remove the var already when written once in the definition....the program ran well.(●'◡'●)(●'◡'●)**

Comment: It is not advised to say "thank you" in comments, and most definitely not in answers.